# Array operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have class A and B.

Class A has some fields.
Class B is like:

```
class B {
public:
    A* operator[]( int id ) {
        return m_field.at( id );
    }
    /* also tried this one, but there are the same errors
    A*& operator[]( int id ) {
        return m_field.at( id );
    }
    */
private:
    vector<A*> m_field;
};
```

why am I getting errors while executing:

```
B* B_instance = new B();
B_instance[some_int]->some_field_from_A;
```

the errors are:

> error C2819: type 'B' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
>
> error C2039: 'some_field_from_A' : is not a member of 'B'

an why do I need to have -> operator overloading and how it should looks like? It doesn't make sense to me.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Did you instantiate `B` as a pointer? It doesn't look like a vector of pointers is really necessary, either.

Comment: This should work, post some real code where the problem is.

Comment: yes, B instance is created as a pointer

Comment: @tobi, Then it's returning something of type `B` because pointers can be indexed like arrays.

Comment: Then that's the error :) Kudos to chris.

Comment: why is `B` holding a vector of `A*` rather than a vector of `A`? Where is the container holding the actual `A` data? This smells very much like flawed design. Why not using `std::vector<A>` instead of `class B`?

Comment: @Walter That's not the subject of the topic. It is very simplified example of my real code and I had some purposes to do that (because A is a bigger class and it is better to store only pointers to instances). Why downvoted btw?

Comment: downvoted because lack of research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexing operator applies to something of type `B`, not of type `B *`. Therefore, to use the indexing operator, you need to first dereference your pointer (or not use one at all):

```
(*B_instance)[some_int]...
```

The reason for the error is because pointers can be indexed, as they are capable of representing an array, as in the example below:

```
int arr[2] = {0, 1};
int *p = arr; //array to pointer conversion
p[1] = 2; // now arr is {0, 2}
```

So when you index a `B *`, it gives you back a `B` that's most likely out of bounds of your imaginary array. Then, you use the arrow operator on that `B` object when it expects a dot operator instead. Either way if you use pointers, dereference it, then index it, then use the arrow.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't look nicely. I think I will just go for A* getItem(int id) method then, because I want B to be created dynamically.